# Extract string from buffer

Tags: java

Below given is the output of my arduino script. I'm using Java (Netbeans IDE) to count the number of steps from the below set of values. I'm storing this set of values in buffer. I want to extract only the time and gyroscope x,y,z values using java. I remember there is a way to point to "Time" and add the index number. But I'm not too sure about that.How can I do that? Please help

Values stored in the Buffer :

Left Leg
Time(ms): 676589

Gyroscope    :    -1.20     ,   -1.38    ,   -3.05

Accelerometer:    -0.03    ,   -0.12     ,   -1.05

Magnetometer :    0.35    ,   0.32     ,   -0.26

Right Leg

Time(ms): 222875

Gyroscope    :    1.53     ,   -0.46    ,   -2.21

Accelerometer:    0.29    ,   -0.69     ,   0.63

Magnetometer :    0.34    ,   -0.31     ,   -0.01

Left Leg

Time(ms): 676710

Gyroscope    :    -1.37     ,   -1.22    ,   -3.15

Accelerometer:    -0.03    ,   -0.12     ,   -1.05

Magnetometer :    0.35    ,   0.32     ,   -0.26
..............................................

Comment: Habe you tried anything?

Comment: What is "buffer?" This buffer? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html

Comment: Yes, I tried to use "index of" function and substring function. But each time I run the code the index number changes. So I need some other function to get the "time" and "gyroscope" values

Comment: try {
                while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    //int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                    char buffer = (char)inputStream.read();
                    this.bufferRx += buffer;
                    //System.out.println(bufferRx);
                    System.out.print(buffer);
                }                                                                                                     this is the code to get the values from the serial port and store to buffer

Comment: @Aleesha Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split each String and extract the values you need:

```
String firstRow = "Left Leg Time(ms): 676589";
String secondRow = "Gyroscope : -1.20 , -1.38 , -3.05";

String[] firstRowParts = firstRow.split(" ");
int time = Integer.parseInt(firstRowParts[3]);   // 676589
String[] secondRowParts = secondRow.split(" ");
int x = Integer.parseInt(secondRowParts[2]);     // -1.20
int y = Integer.parseInt(secondRowParts[4]);     // -1.38
int z = Integer.parseInt(secondRowParts[6]);     // -3.05
```

Comment: String firstRow = "Left Leg Time(ms): 676589";
String secondRow = "Gyroscope : -1.20 , -1.38 , -3.05";                                                                                                   The problem is I have a set of values coming in every millisecond and my final aim is to count the number of steps, which means each millisecond my time and x, y, z values are different. So is there a way to get it from the buffer instead of declaring as the above

Answer (score 0):

To make the above solution more general, 
I would do the following:

```
int time = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 0;
String[] lines = buffer.split("\n")
//you will have the lines here, assuming that you have the Buffer values  in a string called buffer
for(String string in lines){
   if (string.contains("Time")){
     String[] values = string.split(" ");
     time = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);  
   }
   if (string.contains("Gyroscope")){
     String[] values = string.split(" ");
     x = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);   
     y = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);   
     z = Integer.parseInt(values[3]);  
   }
 }
```

I did not test it, so I hope that there are no typo s in it...